# why is epoll triggering multiple read events in level triggered mode?

Tags: c, server, state-machine, epoll

I am writing a state machine using epoll in C. I am tracking a file descriptor that is a tcp socket that accepts connections, as well as the connected file descriptors. After the first read and write events, epoll emits multiple `EPOLLIN` events that would block in a `read` call.

Here is a simplified example of what the code looks like now:

```c
int main()
{
     // omitted socket, bind, listen, epoll_create for length
     num = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, maxev, -1);
     for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
     {
           struct epoll_event event = events[i];
           if (event.data.fd == sfd) 
           {
                 // accept and make socket non blocking
                 int cfd = accpet_connection(event.data.fd);
                 struct epoll_event ee = { 0 };
                 ee.data.fd = cfd;
                 ee.events = EPOLLIN;
                 epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, cfd, &ee);
           }
           else 
           {
                 if (event.events & EPOLLIN) 
                 {
                     // read from fd function called
                     event.events |= EPOLLOUT;
                     epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
                 }
                 if (event.events & EPOLLOUT) 
                 {
                     // write to fd function called
                     event.events |= EPOLLIN;
                     epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &event);
                 }
           }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

when `read` returns 0, the fd is deleted from the epoll instance using `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` and the file descriptor is closed.

My issue is that after the first write has happened, epoll will continuously say that I have a read event. When I read from the file descriptor, -1 is returned with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`

the read function that is used looks like this:

```c
ssize_t read_from_fd(int fd)
{
     ssize_t n;
     printf("read called\n");
     n = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
     if (n == -1)
     {
          if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) 
          {
              printf("read blocked\n");
          }
          return -1;
     }
     if (n == 0)
     {
          // remove fd from epoll instance and close fd
     }
}
```

To demonstrate the output, the server starts, a client connects, the client sends one message, the client reads one message, then the client closes the connection. This is the output:

```bash
$ ./server
accepted connection <fd>
read called
write called
read called
read blocked
read called
closed connection with <fd>
```

Sometimes there are multiple 'read called' and 'read blocked' logs. The amount has ranged from 1 to ~25.

When I removed the `epoll_ctl` function that is called after a write call, I get multiple 'write' events emitted from epoll, and the program crashes with SIGPIPE since the client closes the connection after having received one message.

Comment: What is the structure object `events`? How is it related to the structure object `ee`? Please take some time to make sure that you show us a proper [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `events` are the events tracked by the epoll instance. `ee` is a new event to be added to the interest list of the epoll instance, representing the newly connected file descriptor.

Comment: @boreddad420 In general you want to address issues raised by editing your question so people that wants to help you doesn't have to review all the comments.  A program is way more effective in demonstrating the problem than a set of incomplete snippets.

Comment: @AllanWind I did edit the question for the first comment. If there's anything else I should add to the question to make it clearer, please let me know, as the comment above only addressed the `events` struct and `ee` struct

Comment: @boreddad420 Yes, consolidate your code into a program.  See [mre].  It's particular powerful if you hard-code a failing test case in main.  Currently, it's two incomplete snippets.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [epoll_ctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) (where I have added emphasis):

> EPOLLET
> Requests edge-triggered notification for the associated file descriptor.  **The default behavior for `epoll` is level-triggered.**  See `epoll(7)` for more detailed information about edge-triggered and level-triggered notification.

If you follow the link for [`epoll(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) you will see their lengthy discussion on edge-triggered vs. level-triggered. But in a nutshell, level-triggered behavior means you will keep getting notifications so long as the status is set. In contrast, edge-triggered behavior means you will get a notification only when the status changes from unset to set.

For `EPOLLIN`, level-triggered behavior means so long as there is still something to read in the input queue, the epoll_wait will return.

The edge-triggered behavior would be that epoll-wait will not return if you left data in the input queue after it had notified you. So for edge-triggered, you would need to drain the input queue first before you get another `EPOLLIN` notification.

Of particular interest is the `-1` return on `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`. That is considered to be an event left in the input queue if it has not yet been returned. Not reading it out will cause level-triggered mode to return again, and will prevent edge-triggered from returning when more data arrives behind it.

[Level-Triggered Demo](https://tio.run/##zVRhb9owEP2eX3FjEjJVgLCvtJOyQis0ClNh2qSpitL4oNGCw2yHaar47exsB9J0SKBJkxblg32@e/fey8VJe5kku7epSLKCI1yqX6qL6zzLOk/vvXpY5cl31PV4IVKluYm9TNY8zet5sVIoX9WilCJ3pRwXqUAY3U6m90PoeTtvk6ccNCodZbjBLNIyXS5RIgeWCg24XnAfzEqtv717aMGzt/WqImBmaaJAj0mT/cPS1FY7W@@2yVMs4bFY9D27NXlwBdaNKJEYa2SOYcvlO1HsDbOZlxC0WmWppDpn1zpOJQtvos@T0VcfZtPrj9Fsfj8M73wIfGr@GkrWcLoXMDbyoZJ/0bUnSssi0SU5SjG6kLo@QwBbh4nY4bGOO1YFyew9HOK2QFF4@Gk6Ho8m/QPrUq3OmLPYJkTX83EUDga@g/GhiXiS@ABXuSCaZFuJ@jNONTxm5Ivay6hamsOyJ6H70KM3CIJ6G0q/oi59g6/TFdmRF9pgVa6j4IxYBsSyETcszjGQ3mmmEnUhxXlU271jPaDZBFbZ3dzbXZsTicmG7X2l6bN4d7PbaDCdzL@Eo/lx9oY4zSSnIV6TBwuZr@BHgQUe7DitTOk0y2r2/Q2ZttVp/2azHYa3IUm0BJMM6ZdSOtaFOoPXP5yNJMsVusE4/8svcukKOSS5EP/jJAQvJuFmNPlTb@@g14UMW4psvZ25/VZxKuqXJQ2TYo0PuKQDc5U2yqZmzcq1yxkKXstwrkFgwX8D)

---

Examining your output, and annotating what it means:

```
$ ./server
accepted connection <fd>
read called                 # EPOLLIN, something in queue
write called                # EPOLLOUT, wrote something
read called                 # EPOLLIN, did not hit end of queue yet
read blocked                # you cleared the status flag
read called                 # EPOLLIN, FIN has arrived
closed connection with <fd>
```